# Removing unique writing style from text

Tags: nlp

To start off, I'm not a data scientist or machine learning engineer.  I'm mostly interested in finding existing solutions that will fit this usecase.

I'm trying to build a forum that will protect users privacy.  To my knowledge, it would be possible for malicious attackers who gain access to the forum to run replies through a classifier and be able to roughly group the replies to individual users based on writing style.  Should those attackers also have labeled writing samples from people they are trying to pair with the users of the forum, it is possible that they could find matches and thus dox the user.

What I want to do to try to prevent this form of attack is to run all replies through a one way algorithm that removes styled aspects of replies.  I've tried a number of summarizing APIs, but none I have found seem to work well with short replies.

It would be amazing to get some suggestions here from those more familiar with the space.  Let me know if more details are needed.

Comment: To my knowledge this is not possible, but I'm not up to date with the domain. Also I think the threat to privacy as this kind of advanced style-based method is unlikely, it would require a lot of effort and data by the attacker. Imho the users themselves are usually a more serious threat, in the sense that some of them will unavoidably give clues in their messages without realizing, and somebody who collect all the clues from a user can usually identify them.

Comment: You raise a central point that I think I missed.  While the ML based attack is possibly the most powerful, the more realistic one is just someone noticing a pattern in style.  Ideally this NLP based method would help prevent that.  I can't do anything about the content being revealing, so that's just something I'll have to live with.